# Iphone 4 Screen not working - animating non-stop.

Tags: iphone, display, screen

My Iphone 4 screen doesn't display properly, contents on the screen are animating as shown in the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=olr2kgZ3cTU . Touch is working fine I am able to open apps... but the display is broken. The same behavior as in the video is observed during resetting, rebooting etc..  Tried factory resetting, updating the software etc..

Comment: What is your question here? Yes it's obviously broken and most probably a hardware issue. Do you need help in repairing it?

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a hardware fault. Sorry but you'll need to take it to an Apple Store or somewhere similar to be repaired or replaced.